# Retrieve values from checkbox ajax php javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post, checkbox

I have this code in html:

```
<form id='status_service' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8' name='status_form'>
<fieldset>
<label class="cb-enable"><span>On</span></label>
<label class="cb-disable selected "><span>Off</span></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="id_sf_checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1" name="checkbox" onChange="document.getElementById('status_service').submit(); window.location.reload(true)"/>

<label class="cb-enable"><span>On</span></label>
<label class="cb-disable selected "><span>Off</span></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="id_sf_checkbox" class="checkbox" value="2" name="checkbox" onChange="document.getElementById('status_service').submit(); window.location.reload(true)"/>

<label class="cb-enable "><span>On</span></label>
<label class="cb-disable selected "><span>Off</span></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="id_sf_checkbox" class="checkbox" value="3" name="checkbox" onChange="document.getElementById('status_service').submit(); window.location.reload(true)"/>

<label class="cb-enable "><span>On</span></label>
<label class="cb-disable selected "><span>Off</span></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="id_sf_checkbox" class="checkbox" value="4" name="checkbox" onChange="document.getElementById('status_service').submit(); window.location.reload(true)"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

It creates a iphone styled button (ON/OFF), using CSS for activate/desactivate the service (the value corresponds the id_service the user wants to modify)

I would retrieve this using this code, but, what's wrong:

```
$(document).ready( function()
{
$(".cb-enable").click(function()
{
    var parent = $(this).parents('.switch');
    $('.cb-disable',parent).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.id_sf_checkbox',parent).attr('checked', true);

    alert("Checkbox enabled");
    alert($("input[name=checkbo]:checked").map(function () {return this.value;}).get().join(","));


    $('.ajaxgif').removeClass('hide');

    var checkbox = new Array();
    $("input:checked").each(function()
    {
        data['checkbox[]'].push($(this).val());
    });

    alert(checkbox);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../proceso_checkboxes.php",
        data: {checkbox:checkbox},

        success: function()
        {
            $('.ajaxgif').hide();
            $('.msg').text('Mensaje enviado!').addClass('msg_ok').animate({ 'right' : '130px' }, 300);
        },
        error: function()
        {
            $('.ajaxgif').hide();
            $('.msg').text('Hubo un error!').addClass('msg_error').animate({ 'right' : '130px' }, 300);
        }
    });



});

$(".cb-disable").click(function()
{
    var parent = $(this).parents('.switch');
    $('.cb-enable',parent).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.id_sf_checkbox',parent).attr('checked', false);
    alert("Checkbox disabled");
    showSelectedValues();
});

$("input[type=checkbox][id=id_sf_checkbox][checked]").each(function()
{
    var parent = $(this).parents(".switch");
    $(".cb-enable",parent).addClass("selected");
    $(".cb-disable",parent).removeClass("selected");
});
});
```

My objective is to send the values of the checkbox to the php, but in the javascript alerts function shows blank, no values, and i do not know what's wrong, i've been looking a solution, and tested, but stills appears blank.

Any help? thanks in advance.

Attached below the CSS code about the checkboxes:

```
/* Checkboxes */
span.jqTransformCheckboxWrapper {display:block;float:left}
a.jqTransformCheckbox {background:transparent url(../images/checkbox.gif) no-repeat left -30px;vertical-align:middle;height:17px;width:17px;display:block;/*display:-moz-inline-block;*/}
/* Checked - Used for both Radio and Checkbox */
a.jqTransformChecked {background-position:left top}
/* Hidden - used to hide the original form elements */
.jqTransformHidden {display:none}


/* Formulario de login-home status service form */
#status_service .cb-enable, .cb-disable, .cb-enable span, .cb-disable span { background: url(../images/switch.gif) repeat-x; display: block; float: left; }
#status_service .cb-enable span, .cb-disable span { line-height: 30px; display: block; background-repeat: no-repeat; font-weight: bold; }
#status_service .cb-enable span { background-position: left -90px; padding: 0 10px; }
#status_service .cb-disable span { background-position: right -180px;padding: 0 10px; }
#status_service .cb-disable.selected { background-position: 0 -30px; }
#status_service .cb-disable.selected span { background-position: right -210px; color: #fff; }
#status_service .cb-enable.selected { background-position: 0 -60px; }

#status_service .cb-enable.selected span { background-position: left -150px; color: #fff; }
#status_service .switch label { cursor: pointer; }
#status_service .switch input { display: none; }

/* Mod para AJAX gif */
#status_service  .ultimo{ margin-bottom: 0; position: relative; }
/* AJAX Gif y mensajes de exito o fracaso */
#status_service .hide{display: none; }
#status_service .ajaxgif{position: absolute; right: 150px; top: 5px; }
#status_service .msg{color: white; font-weight: bold; height: 32px; line-height: 32px; padding: 0 10px; position: absolute; right: -155px; text-transform: uppercase; min-width: 121px; }
#status_service .msg_ok{background: #589D05; }
#status_service .msg_error{background: red; }
```

Comment: You are using the same name for multiple checkboxes. Do you mean to use a radio instead?

Comment: i need checkboxes, they look like on/off with css style.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an `x` in your selector.

```
alert($("input[name=checkbox]:checked")
                 ----------^
```

Comment: @undefined: The OP had `name=checkbo`, when it should have been `name=checkbox`. However, this looks like something the OP added for debugging purposes. I doubt he's really concerned about why the alert itself doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, here `alert($("input[name=checkbo]:checked").map(function () {return this.value;}).get().join(","));`

Comment: It was a mistake, i've forgotten the 'x' but still not working, the alert appears, but isn't showing the checkbox values. Any values are passed to the php post.

Comment: This returns values to me, in array: 'alert($("input[name=checkbox]").map(function () {return this.value;}).get().join(","));'  but I want the one which has changed, if I add the "checked" is not working

Answer (score 0):

Simply make `checkbox` as array, it will give you all checkboxes checked in an array.

```
var checkbox = new Array();
$("input:checked").each(function()
{
    checkbox.push($(this).val());
});

alert(checkbox);
```

Comment: @ChrisPratt where do you see `data` variable?

Comment: I wanna to pass de checkboxes values to a php page for processing, and for testing purposes i've mounted the alert to debug and see that's no values captured. Thanks i've tested your solution but no values are showed in the alert too.

Comment: This returns values to me, in array: 'alert($("input[name=checkbox]").map(function () {return this.value;}).get().join(","));'  but I want the one which has changed, if I add the "checked" is not working

Comment: It's really hard to see without css. And what I've pasted you it returns the checkboxes checked.